# Polymer app-drawer left hanging wrapper when closed & content not take up all space

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-2.x, gmaps.js

I was trying to build an app with layout like youtube web (www.youtube.com), here is my code :

```
      <app-drawer-layout>

        <app-drawer id="menuDrawer" slot="drawer">
          <div class="drawer-contents">
            <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
              <span>inbox</span>
            </paper-icon-item>
            <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="favorite" item-icon slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
              <span>favorite</span>
            </paper-icon-item>
            <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="polymer" item-icon slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
              <span>polymer</span>
            </paper-icon-item>
            <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="question-answer" item-icon slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
              <span>question-answer</span>
            </paper-icon-item>
            <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="send" item-icon slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
              <span>send</span>
            </paper-icon-item>
            <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="archive" item-icon slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
              <span>archive</span>
            </paper-icon-item>
            <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="backup" item-icon slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
              <span>backup</span>
            </paper-icon-item>
            <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="dashboard" item-icon slot="item-icon"></iron-icon>
              <span>dashboard</span>
            </paper-icon-item>
          </div>
        </app-drawer>

        <app-toolbar>
          <paper-icon-button id="menuButton" icon="menu" on-tap="_onToggle"></paper-icon-button>
        </app-toolbar>

        <div id="navigationMap" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

      </app-drawer-layout>
```

more complete code was at jsbin : https://jsbin.com/sizeruducu/edit?html,output. I'm facing some problems:

1. Whenever the toggle button clicked, the app drawer at left was gone, but not with it's wrapper, this left the right content hanging in the right side. Unlike [youtube web](https://www.youtube.com), whenever I tried to click the top left menu button, it will hide the menu drawer, and the right content will fill all the left space.
2. My google maps won't fit all the space, even when I tried to change it to 100% height, it just won't fit. I want to make it take up all the space (width and height).

Any comment and answer will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follwoing changes are required:

- Toggle function to hide the `drawer`:

  ```
  _onToggle() {
      //this.$.menuDrawer.toggle();
      var drawerLayout = this.$.drawerLayout;
      if (drawerLayout.forceNarrow || !drawerLayout.narrow) {
        drawerLayout.forceNarrow = !drawerLayout.forceNarrow;

      } else {
        drawerLayout.drawer.toggle();
      }
  }
  ```

  Instead of toggling the `app-drawer`, you have to change the layout of `app-drawer-layout`.
- `app-drawer-layout`:

  `<app-drawer-layout force-narrow id="drawerLayout" fullbleed >`

  The `fullbleed` attribute will make it fit the size of its container. 
  `force-narrow` attribute to force to make narrow layout as you want it to 
  be.
- To change the height of the navigation:

  ```
  this.$.navigationMap.style.height = window.innerHeight+'px';
  ```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/zesuwazacu/3/edit?html,output)

If you want to make it like [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/). [Click here](https://jsbin.com/bakozu/4/edit?html,output).

The default value of `responsiveWidth` attribute of `app-drawer-layout` is `640px`, so you must increase the `width` of output in jsbin.